# regex trying to match without pluses

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"funny+gifs-politics+aww".match(/\+(\w+)/gis)
```

Returns array with `[+gifs, +aww]`, when I'm looking for `[gifs, aww]`. It doesn't seem to make a difference where I put the parenthesis.

```
"funny+gifs-politics+aww".match(/(\+\w+)/gis)
```

Same result. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: The `match()` function only matches the given regex as is, ignoring groups. Just wanted to highlight that. The answers already given below provide workable solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the [`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) will only provide the full match element and the parenthesis will just create [capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups), so to get all the matches you should use [`String.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), then identify which capturing group are you looking for. But if the pattern for your case is always known like `+` sign you can simply use [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to get what you wanted.

```js
console.log("funny+gifs-politics+aww".match(/\+(\w+)/gis).map(item => item.replace('+', '')))
```

Also as Toto said earlier you can use [positive look behind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) to match the element if only a particular element *(Like `+`)* exists before it.

```js
console.log("funny+gifs-politics+aww".match(/(?<=\+)\w+/gis))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.matchAll()` method, which I believe is fairly new.

```js
const res = "funny+gifs-politics+aww".matchAll(/\+(\w+)/gis);
const subs = [];

for (const r of res) {
  console.log(r);
  subs.push(r[1]);
}

console.log(subs);
```

---

Otherwise you can use `.exec()` in a loop.

```js
const re = /\+(\w+)/gis;
const s = "funny+gifs-politics+aww";
let match = null;
const subs = [];

while((match = re.exec(s))) {
  console.log(match);
  subs.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(subs);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a positive lookbehind `(?<=\+)` to make sure to have a plus before words but without capture it.

```js
res = "funny+gifs-politics+aww".match(/(?<=\+)\w+/gis);
console.log(res);
```